# Publishing vscode extension failed due to validation error: 'contains an entry which is unsafe for extraction'

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've got an vscode extension successfully published and updated in market for several versions.

Today after publishing a new version from command line as usual, I got a mail that said it failed due to a validation error. The attached log only said "the extension contains an entry which is unsafe for extraction".

But the only changes in this version were just some adds and deletes in an existing file. I've tried to publish again and the result was the same. So I'm very confused what going wrong here, and the more important question is: How could I get the extension updated again?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same with an extension that is built in an Azure DevOps pipeline and then released via a DevOps pipeline.

Comment: @MichaelJolley How did u solve it? I'm experiencing the same issue. But the error message is not clear and helpful at all.

Comment: As of yet, I haven’t resolved it.